# Should asking syntax related questions always lead to a "not enough research done" downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, asking-questions

Syntax documentation is always available for everyone.

So, should asking a question related to syntax **always** end in a downvote, because the questioner didn't search through the helpfiles or documents?

Related question [Excel VBA - Loop Numbered Variables [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800268/excel-vba-loop-numbered-variables/71802532#71802532)

Comment: If you didn't think it was a good question, why did you answer it? (No offense intended, just curious.)

Comment: No I didn't. I was wondering why someone was downvoting a beginners question. Perhaps this guy was not able to define "the right spelling of the search term" to get to its right answer. I was answering him because I believe it's sometimes hard for new people to ask the right questions using the right words. I've also seen there were already a couple of views on that question, what was leading me to the conclusion that the question is interesting for more than this one guy. So I thought it could be helpful for others to answer.

Comment: without knowledge of the question how can we can give an **opinion** if it merits a downvote

Comment: FWIW, I don't get why you think that question is "syntax related". They seem to ask how to approach the problem at all; that this involves writing syntactically correct code doesn't make it a question about syntax.

Comment: He wrote _"I have no experience working with arrays."_
But I guess you are right. I made the assumption that he doesn't now how to use an array because he doesn't understand the syntax. Therefore I gave him some examples so he is able to solve his problem by himself.
But the word "experience" doesn't imply WHAT his problem is if he is using Arrays.

Comment: 'I have no experience working with arrays." oh, THAT question.  I downvoted that immediate.  I'm sorry, but I have lost all patience and sympathy with such questions.  The poster has not reached even 'novice' level and needs to go back to tutorial books/sites to learn basics of data structures and how they are addressed:(

Comment: So, .... that means to me I shouldn't answers beginners questions because SO community is getting bored of those questions ? Then I misunderstood SO totally wrong....

I think I shouldn't overrate downvotes. Also downvoted questions and answers can help people. Downvotes are more a indicator for the communites average experience level.

Perhaps this is the wrong place if I want to help other peoples with my skills ?
I believe I didn't get SOs target right.

Comment: @MaMe you did not get SO's goal wrong, you are just misinterpreting what should be done in what case. We accept beginner questions just fine, but as this is a repository of knowledge rather than a help desk, we strive for usefulness to *future* readers as opposed to providing help for the author. The latter is important, but should not override the concern about future readers. Most of beginner questions have already been asked and answered - vote (flag) to close questions that are good *signposts* as *duplicates*. VTC as unclear those lacking details...

Comment: ...VTC as no repro/typo those that are too specific to be helpful to anyone else other than the OP. VTC as unclear those that lack the required details (i.e. where you feel like asking the author a question). VTC as off-topic those that are not a good fit for the site. Finally, and probably most importantly, downvote low-quality questions (which includes the post in question - as it is not a *good* signpost for the duplicate target).

Comment: Not enough research is not a good reason to downvote to begin with, that's only half of the tooltip and it's the lead in part, not the clue. It's the unclear and not useful bits that are the actual reasons to downvote. USUALLY one follows the other, but not always.

Comment: Ok. I think I have to answer less. First I have to get an understanding on how a good question have to look like. Thank you guys.

Comment: Now I also understand why alot of question only get comments instead of answers.Bad question will mess up the auto clean up of SO.

Comment: @MaMe well yes, I'm on the fence of that is actually a good reason to make decisions though. You shouldn't answer low quality/off-topic questions because of the established rules and regulations (and because you might get answer banned...), not because of the automated cleanup bots that we should pretty much be blissfully ignorant of. Stack Overflow is difficult enough to understand as it is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Always? No. The conclusion doesn't follow. The documentation might *not* be available, or it might be unclear, or there might be some edge-case not covered in the documentation, or the question might just be well-written and extremely useful as a reference for others *even though it is covered in the documentation*.

Votes should be based strictly on the quality and usefulness of the post; nothing more, nothing less.

[The question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71800268) is rather low quality, difficult to read, unlikely to be a useful reference for others, and…not a syntax-related question.

Answer (score 6):

[This question is about syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c/) and has a score of almost 10K, so I'm going to say no. The general consensus seems to be that that one at least deserves upvotes rather than downvotes.

What we're looking for is that the question is interesting or useful in some way. Of course what's interesting and useful is different to different people, but if you need the answer and it's the first thing to come up in your search then why not upvote both the question and any helpful answers?

Documentation may exist in more than one place and may be contradictory or even inconsistent with the system or library it's documenting. Explanations of what's going on would certainly be helpful in such circumstances.

Being the hundredth person to ask some question about syntax is likely to get you downvotes though because marking the 100th duplicate isn't very interesting and certainly does indicate you didn't try very hard to find any of those 100 existing duplicates. Research certainly does help to avoid that particular pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is usually written on the (implicit) assumption that the person reading the documentation understands the concepts involved, has no prior misconceptions about them which need to be cleared up, and is able to use their knowledge to make correct inferences about how the factual statements in the documentation apply to particular examples.

For a large number of programmers, especially novices, those assumptions are not all true, so we can't say that if only they had read the documentation, then they wouldn't have needed to ask their question. Consider this example:

> Why is `-3 ** 2` equal to `-9` but when I write `x = -3` then `x ** 2` is `9`?

The confusion is purely about syntax: the asker thinks `-3 ** 2` means `(-3) ** 2` when it actually means `-(3 ** 2)`. And surely the docs will say that the `**` operator has higher precedence than the unary `-` operator, which is essentially the answer. But for this part of the docs to clear up their question, the asker would need to already understand:

- What "operator precedence" means,
- That the `-` operator in their code is the "unary" `-` operator,
- That the problem *is* caused by incorrect operator precedence and not some quirk that causes different behaviour for literal values vs. variables,
- That, mathematically, the result `9` is the correct one, so the problem is in the first expression, not the second one.

Of course, if they were asking *this exact question* then you could close it as a duplicate of an existing question because there are lots of people who have asked this exact question before. In that case you might judge that a downvote is justified because they (apparently) didn't look for existing answers to their exact question. But there are lots of analogous syntax-based questions where there is some part of the docs that answers the question, but it only answers the question if you already understand the answer, as it were. For questions like that, Stack Overflow Q&As can be valuable for the many programmers whose current understanding is not sufficient to get that value from the docs.